# Consulta para mostrar datos de un formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql

¿Cómo hago para que mi computadora muestre los datos en la misma página de un formulario simultáneamente cuando son enviados a una base de datos?

Es para una sección de comentarios que tengo planeado poner en la pagina web que estoy creando y, también ponerle la fecha y hora respectiva a cada comentario.

Este es el formulario:

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="POST">
        <Label for="nombre">Nombre:</Label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" required=""placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."><br><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"  required=""placeholder="Escribe tu email..."> <br><br>
        <label for="clave">Clave:</label>
        <input type="password" name="clave" required="" placeholder="Escribe tu clave..."><br><br>
        <label for="comentario">Comentario:</label>
       <textarea type="comentario" name="comentario" cols="90px" rows="8" required="" placeholder="Escriba aquí su comentario..."></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Comentar">

    </form>
```

Esta es la conexión PHP:

```
<?php 

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try { 
  echo "datos enviados correctamente";
$sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
$sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
$sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
$sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
$sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
$sql->execute();
 }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e->getMessage();
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: incluyendo AJAX para que haga las llamadas de forma asíncrona y al mismo tiempo que haces el alta, se muestre la información en elgún elemento HTML que designes

Comment: ¿Me explicas con mas claridad? php y html son los únicos lenguajes que conozco mejor, así que estaría completamente perdido si implementase ajax al documento html

Answer (score 0):

Así como leo tu planteamiento del problema, deberias recargar la pagina, despues de realizar la insercion de tus datos, obvio tambien ya deberias mostrar los comentarios que tienes en tu BD en divs o en una tabla

Solucion rapida:

```
//Tu conexion
$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try {
  //La insercion de la información
  $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
  $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
  $sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
  $sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
  $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
  $sql->execute();
//Verificas si la información se agrego exitosamente
  if($sql){
      //Le muestras al usuario un mensaje de feedback y lo rediriges al sitio que tu quieras
      echo "alert('datos enviados correctamente'); location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'; ";

  }else{
    // este es el caso contrario, solo cambia el mensaje
    echo "alert('error al enviar los datos'); location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'; ";
  }
 }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e->getMessage();
 }
```

Tambien la implementacion de AJAX es mas util como lo comento [shadow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75901/shadow)